# How do I achieve this edge with a router?

Tags: router

I'm essentially restoring a bathroom in a 1920s house and I'm trying to be as true to the original woodwork as I can (as a novice).

I'm using my dad's old router for the first time ever and so far it's been going OK (not perfect, but OK).

One edge that I haven't been able to figure out is the edge of the window sill. It's got sort of an "S" shape (if you cut off the bottom third and the top right downward curve).

The convex portion of the curve at the top goes 180° around and is definitely a 1/4" radius curve and I think maybe that the concave lower portion is perhaps a 1/2" radius curve.

I went to Home Depot and lowes to try and find a bit (or bits) that I could use to do this. The closest thing I found was a 1/4" radius Roman bit that could do the bottom of the sill (though the radius isn't right for that) and I thought maybe I could find a 1/2" radius one, but when I thought about it, I realized that in doing the top 1/4" curve (if I've already done the bottom curve), there would be nothing for the bearing to guide the second cut. I'd have the reverse issue if I did the top curve first.

So how do I do this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

*Edit*:

Someone suggested that I mount the router underneath a plywood table. However, I do not immediately see a way to mount it. There are screws underneath the rods that I *could* use, but they are metal screws, not wood screws. Could I use the holes on the guide attached to the rods to screw it into the side of a table?

[image]

Comment: I just measured how far the bottom edge is from the outer edge and it's a half inch. The wood is 1" thick exactly and the curve at the top is definitely a 1/4" radius curve, so I no longer think that the concave curve on the bottom is 1/2". Can't be. Must be 1/4 concave and 1/4" convex above it, but smoothed out of 3/4" of height, so to speak.

Comment: If you can't find the exact bit, you'll need to play around with a few different bits, and for this, you probably need a router table. Lucky for you, that can be a hunk of plywood suspended between milk crates with a router bolted onto the underside and a stick clamped on top.

Comment: @Aloysius Defenestrate - *That's* a very interesting idea. I already had been using a plywood piece on saw horses with a strip of wood screwed down to keep boards from moving. I wonder if my craftsman router has mount points...

Comment: Now what I saw below if the router-based option since of course you do have a router as you've indicated. I'm not going to add a competing Answer since I think @bowlturner's is perfectly sufficient, but I wanted to mention that you could quite easily do this on the cheap with some hand planing followed by a scratch stock (plus some *very* minor blending in with sanding). In addition to this costing essentially zero going this route means you'd be done faster even than if you could drive somewhere to buy the necessary bits, much less waiting for delivery of the first bit from an online vendor.

Comment: Google ‘stool router bit’. The bad thing is that these tend to be big, so might not be suited to your router. And attaching a router to a table usually involves removing the baseplate and using longer screws through those holes.

Comment: OMG, there's a "sill router bit" that looks exactly right and I found it when googling "stool router bit" as you suggested.

Comment: But damn, the shank is a 1/2" and my router takes 1/4"

Comment: I'm not surprised the shank is 1/2" -- those are pretty big bits, requiring a pretty big router in a table. Maybe borrow? And don't lose hope... you can still build up to the profile in multiple passes with an assortment of bits.

Comment: So this is the bit I'd like to use, but I'd like to not have to buy a second router with a 1/2" collett. But the closest place I found to rent one is a half hour drive away. Are there any other tool rental places that would likely have one? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Yonico-Window-Sill-1-3-8-in-L-1-2-in-Shank-Carbide-Tipped-Router-Bit-18140/304970786  Tried Home Depot, lowes, true value, ace, RAC, united, and the Sunbelt (which is a 1/2 hr away).

Comment: We can see you *really* want to get the bit :-) and of course it is your money, but seriously, if you'd gone one of the alternate routes you'd probably be done already. How many of these sills do you need to re-make?

Comment: *"but they are metal screws, not wood screws."* As mentioned in a couple of recent Q&As, machine screws actually hold really well in wood if a pilot hole is sized right (more critical with machine threads than with wood-screw threading). After that threads can be cut in using a rudimentary tap made from one of the screws (useful for harder hardwoods) or for softer materials just forced in. If felt necessary dribbling in superglue is the standard way to increase the hole wall strength and it works very well. Alternatively, you can use bolts and nuts so no threading required.

Comment: I'm all about the journey. I enjoy solving problems and I'm a perfectionist. If I wanted close enough, I'd have been done with this whole remodel a long time ago. ;) I'm only remaking 1 sill, though if I decide to remake the old built in medicine cabinet in the future, it had the same sill, but I don't expect to do that at anytime in the predictable future.

Comment: Incidentally, I looked for alternative bits suggested at both home depot and Lowe's last night and neither had any of the 4 bits discussed thus far - not even the simple Roman 1/4" radius bits. There was a Roman 1/8" bit. I was prepared last night to get one of those and do 2 passes. The selection however is simply abysmal. Maybe it's the same supply issues I've had with multiple items during this remodel that home depot blamed on the pandemic.

Comment: Regarding the machine screws holding the router to the “table”… the head is on the top surface of the table, then threading into the router base. So all you need on the top of the table is a countersunk clearance hole. (And probably longer machine screws.)

Comment: Incidentally, one idea I had last night after my trip to the stores, was to use my tablesaw to "route" the sill. My tablesaw blade will rotate 45° and I realize that with maybe a dozen passes or so (and some sanding), I could reproduce the curve without a router. I'm sure you guys would think that's insane but I think it's cool as a "thinking outside the box" solution.

Comment: Not insane to use a tablesaw. I've faked linenfold carving on one...

Comment: Perfect result is possible using scraping. Good enough for Garret Hack, good enough for any perfectionist :)

Answer (score 3):

I might try an Ogee bit with a board upside down and then use a 1/4 radius after that 'on the top'.  Should be able to get this pretty close with the right Ogee bit, probably a bigger one.

I'm sure I've seen single bits close to that, I have this finger pull door pull that is 'close' but a bit more aggressive on the 'bottom'.  https://www.google.com/shopping/product/13986480099114392013?q=router+bits+door+pull+freud&prds=eto:13639532660545370309_0,pid:9685896006746805321,rsk:PC_10815388883686490806.  I'll keep looking to see if I can find another.  The finger pull might be pushing a full 1" board.

Comment: I just found this bit, but I only have the image. I don't know what it's called or what it's dimensions are, but the middle of the bit looks extremely close to what my sills are... https://images.app.goo.gl/3eYddNF6orfBxXU4A

Comment: @hepcat72, yeah have to say the very first thing I thought here was "two passes, with two different bits" *on a router table* (or the cheapest stand-in for one, which costs nothing). You could maybe find something very similar, as you have in fact, but specialist single-purpose bits are for me only worth it it there's a requirement for very long lengths of the needed profile. *Much* preferable IMO to get might-use-many-times bits, even if it does take a bit of time and a test piece or two to dial in the multi-bit profile.

Comment: @hepcat72 the one you linked to can be found in most hardware stores that sell any router bits if you want to go look at one and take a few measurements.

Comment: @hepcat72 After seeing which router you have, pretty sure that is a 1/4" shank, all the bigger bits that could do the whole shape are going to be 1/2" shank, so you are back to using 2 passes  to get your shape.

Answer (score 3):

- Create accurate profile of edge using gauge or playing cards held by rubber band.

[image]

- Draw profile on both ends of short test board.
- Remove most excess wood on table saw, **stay outside lines**.
- Round off top edge with plane or by sanding, start with 60 or 80.
- Make scratch stock from scraps of hardwood.
- Draw bottom of profile on steel with Sharpie, file to shape, hone
- Scrape bottom curve using scratch stock

After checking new work matches old:

- Cut new sill board slightly long.
- Repeat all steps on new sill.
- Complete by sanding profile to same grit as used on top surface.
- Trim both ends.
- Drink to celebrate spending $0?

[Make Your Own Scratch Stocks](https://www.finewoodworking.com/membership/pdf/86729/011254067.pdf) by Garrett Hack
[How to Make & Use a Scratch Stock for Woodworking](https://woodandshop.com/make-use-scratch-stock-woodworking-david-ray-pine/) by Joshua Farnsworth
[Posts tagged 'scratch stock'](https://pfollansbee.wordpress.com/tag/scratch-stock/) by Peter Follansbee